# How to use VisualSVN with a solution shared between VS 2005 and VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, visual-studio-2005, projects-and-solutions

After looking at other questions related to sharing solutions between VS 2005 and VS 2008 it seems that the way to go is to have two solution files (one for VS 2005 and one for VS 2008).

However, if the solution is under source control (VisualSVN in our case), how would we maintain two solution files and not keep overwriting one or the other with each update/commit?

Is it possible to remove just the .sln file from source control and stop the VisualSVN client from checking its status in visual studio?

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I see the problem - if you've got two solution files, why would either of them be overwritten? I do really mean two files, e.g. MyApp2005.sln and MyApp2008.sln, where when you create a new project you do it in the 2005 solution and then just "add existing project" in the 2008 solution.

What would VisualSVN do to mess this up?

(I have the same setup for my [C# in Depth source code](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx), and I use VisualSVN - I haven't seen any problems.)

Answer (score 0):

It's working now.

I was trying to upgrade/convert the solution to 2008 (solution name the same as the 2005 one) and somehow block the 2008 solution file from commit/update.

I have now created a new blank solution in VS 2008 (different name) and used "add existing project" as you suggested.

Thanks

Matt